# Interpolation of 3d textures in Metal kernel functions not working on Radeon gpu

Tags: ios, macos, metal

I recently got the late 2016 MacBook Pro with a Radeon 445 gpu and now I'm having trouble with kernel functions that is running fine on both iOS and El Capitan with Nvidia gpu's. It seems that 3D textures are not interpolated in the Z axis, even if I specify my sampler like this:

```
constexpr sampler s = sampler(coord::normalized,
                              address::repeat,
                              filter::linear);
```

The problem is very visible in this image:
[image: screenshot where Z goes from left to right]

I've tried forcing Intel Iris graphics (integrated) by using:

```
NSArray *devices = MTLCopyAllDevices();
device = devices[1];
```

Instead of

```
device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
```

But that doesn't give me an context at all, even though

```
device = devices[0];
```

works just fine.

I've tried switching from halfs to floats in the kernels, but without any different result.

UPDATE: As suggested below by Ken, creating the sampler state on the cpu and passing it as an uniform seems to do the trick:

```
MTLSamplerDescriptor *samplerDescriptor = [MTLSamplerDescriptor new];
samplerDescriptor.minFilter = MTLSamplerMinMagFilterLinear;
samplerDescriptor.magFilter = MTLSamplerMinMagFilterLinear;
samplerDescriptor.sAddressMode = MTLSamplerAddressModeRepeat;
samplerDescriptor.tAddressMode = MTLSamplerAddressModeRepeat;
samplerDescriptor.rAddressMode = MTLSamplerAddressModeRepeat;
id<MTLSamplerState> sampler = [device newSamplerStateWithDescriptor:samplerDescriptor];
[commandEncoder setSamplerState:sampler atIndex:0];
```

In shader:

```
sampler s [[sampler(0)]]
```

I'm still very interested to learn why and when the constexpr sampler would fail on Radeon hardware in 3 dimensions.

Comment: Things to try if you haven't: specify `min_filter`, `mag_filter`, and (perhaps) `mip_filter` independently, instead of `filter`. Try `bicubic` instead of `linear` just to see if it matters. Try creating a `MTLSamplerState` object and passing that down via the API rather than a sampler defined in shader code.

Comment: Creating the MTLSamplerState on CPU like you suggests solves the problem. Thank you! Any idea why, or this is a known bug?

Comment: bicubic is not defined I think, at least I can't access it.

Comment: I'm glad that works around the issue. I don't know why and I have no prior experience with this issue. It was just a shot in the dark. Regarding `bicubic`, I got that from the Metal Shader Language spec, but haven't tried it, either.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, creating a `MTLSamplerState` object and passing that down via the API rather than a sampler defined in shader code works around the problem.

Comment: I can confirm, but I cannot get interpolation to work on RG8Uint textures, even with passing down the sampler state object. Workaround is using RG16float for now.